# Reshape in R, rows to vectors

Tags: r, aggregate, reshape

My data looks like the following:

```
fruit          ID
apple          1
mango          1
orange         1
grapes         2
strawberries   3
```

What i want to do using reshape is the foll:

```
ID     Fruit
 1     apple,mango,orange 
 2     grapes
 3     strawberries
```

I tried reshape

```
rehshape(data=test,direction="long",varying=c(1,2),v.names="v1",timevar="v2",times=c(1,2))->test.long
```

but that's obviously wrong.

Comment: I think you have your terminology all wrong. First, what do you mean by "rows to vectors"? Second, what you show in your output is actually more descriptive of aggregation, not reshaping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `aggregate`

```
aggregate(fruit ~ ID, data , paste, sep=',')

  ID                fruit
1  1 apple, mango, orange
2  2               grapes
3  3         strawberries
```

Answer (score 2):

Since everyone else has `aggregate` covered, here's a way to make `reshape` work for you: Add a time variable to your `data.frame` and then try to reshape from long to wide. Assuming your original `data.frame` is called "mydf":

```
> # Create a time variable
> mydf$time <- ave(mydf$ID, mydf$ID, FUN = seq_along)
> mydf
         fruit ID time
1        apple  1    1
2        mango  1    2
3       orange  1    3
4       grapes  2    1
5 strawberries  3    1

> # Now, reshape
> reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar = "ID", timevar = "time")
  ID      fruit.1 fruit.2 fruit.3
1  1        apple   mango  orange
4  2       grapes    <NA>    <NA>
5  3 strawberries    <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: @Roshini, I'm sorry, but I don't know what you are referring to. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
> aggregate(fruit~ID, data=DF, FUN=paste0)
  ID                fruit
1  1 apple, mango, orange
2  2               grapes
3  3         strawberries
```

Comment: Hard to not give you and @geektrader both upvotes when I had posted virtually the same answer :)